# waitForCondition is not working but Thread.sleep makes the script work

Tags: java, selenium

When I apply `Thread.sleep(2000)` application works well but on `waitForCondition` it fails. Is there any better way to use `waitForCondition` function?  Please provide some examples. Can we give `//h1[@class='some'] in waitForCondition`? or `waitForCondition` works on specific way?

I have used as:

```
selenium.waitForCondition("selenium.isElementPresent(\"//div[@id='pagging-section']\")","5000");
```

But that fails. `Thread.sleep` works well, but I have been advised not to use this method.

Please share with me the proper use of `waitForCondition` and any other better way to wait and find the element and proceed.

Comment: *"Pls share with me.."*  Please spell words properly.  This is not a text message.

Comment: try selenium.isElementPresent("id=pagging-section") to check if you write properly name of id which could exists :)

Comment: yes it will work.. even my code also work...but some time fails...i just created this thread to know any better way to use waitforCondition. Also will it work for any kind of xpath, say //h1[@class='some']..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There can be a lag between when selenium *thinks* the page has loaded and it *actually* loads. Basically, I had the same problem.

I wrote my own little framework to handle this situation: While checking for conditions, I had a loop with `Thread.sleep(200)` that caught any "not found" exceptions and gave up after a timeout (I used 20 seconds) and it works great.

Use `Thread.sleep()`

Comment: waitForCondition is actually a loop equivalent to java code you receive for waitForElementPresnt in selenium-ide..I am looking any better way where it works always..

Comment: @Tarun Yes, it gives consistent results. If there is javascript that executes on page load, you have to give that time to run. It could be that the element you're waiting for is created by javascript. Also, even without this issue, sometimes you just need to wait! Call it a bug with selenium, call it what you want, but we use lots of selenium tests on our CI box, and sleeping briefly is well proven for us as needed.

Comment: Reading the detailed description I am bound to assume that you are aware of disadvantages of sleep. Today I was trying waitForCondition and it did not work for me, and sleep indeed worked. I was almost about to use sleep But then I used a loop to check presence of element, while using conditional sleep. And it worked. You know my choice now...